Heroku Deploy Webpack Not Found
I'm struggling with a Heroku deploy webpack not found error. I've gone thoroughly through my package json, the Heroku node js trouble shooting guide, chatgpt suggestions and many google searches.
To be honest, there isn't a lot of info in the Heroku tails log or otherwise. Looking for pointers. Happy to post more here but I don't see long threads so I held back for this initial Q&A. It's a vanilla js deploy on 5.91, Node 18.x, NPM 10.x. Works fine on local.
What else can I tell you. Some info below. Github Repo: https://github.com/stevecalla/attendance_app_edx
Not A Lot of Detail From Heroku:
remote: > cd client && npm run build remote: remote: remote: > build remote: > webpack --mode production remote: remote: sh: 1:
webpack: not found Entry Point: client folder src/js/index.js using workbox;
also have a client folder package json where webpack lives, webpack.config.js (in client folder), server folder with package and root level package
Resources Consulted (among others): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys Webpack not found, deploying to Heroku
client package json
{
  "name": "attendance_app_edx",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.3.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "idb": "^6.1.2"
  }
}


server package json
{
  "name": "attendance_app_edx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "server:watch": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "chalk": "^5.3.0",
      "clipboardy": "^3.0.0",
      "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
      "cryptr": "^6.3.0",
      "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
      "fuse.js": "^6.6.2",
      "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
      "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
      "string-similarity": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}

root level package json
{
  "name": "attendance_app_edx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x",
    "npm": "10.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"cd client && npm run build && npm run start\" \"cd server && npm run server\" ",
    "start": "npm run build && cd server && node server.js",
    "server": "cd server node server.js --ignore client",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --dev"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}

entry file src/js/index.js
import { Workbox } from 'workbox-window';
import '../css/styles.css';

// Check if service workers are supported
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Register workbox service worker
  // const workboxSW = new Workbox('./src-sw.js');
  const workboxSW = new Workbox('./service-worker.js');
  workboxSW.register();
} else {
  console.error('Service workers are not supported in this browser.');
}

Enumerating objects: 28362, done.
Counting objects: 100% (28362/28362), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (18079/18079), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28362/28362), 37.28 MiB | 1.92 MiB/s, done.
Total 28362 (delta 8325), reused 28106 (delta 8171), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8325/8325), done.
remote: Updated 21594 paths from 726b829b
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):   18.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):    10.x
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 18.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 18.20.3...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 10.x (replacing 10.7.0)...
remote:        npm 10.8.1 installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Prebuild
remote:        Running heroku-prebuild
remote:        
remote:        > attendance_app_edx@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild
remote:        > npm install --dev
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > attendance_app_edx@1.0.0 install
remote:        > cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 192 packages in 621ms
remote:        
remote:        28 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 2 packages in 2s
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        added 169 packages, and audited 170 packages in 13s
remote:        
remote:        22 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        To address all issues, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:        
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        
remote:        > attendance_app_edx@1.0.0 install
remote:        > cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 192 packages in 732ms
remote:        
remote:        28 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 2 packages in 1s
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 170 packages in 3s
remote:        
remote:        22 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        To address all issues, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:        
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > attendance_app_edx@1.0.0 build
remote:        > cd client && npm run build
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > build
remote:        > webpack --mode production
remote:        
remote: sh: 1: webpack: not found
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to fathomless-headland-77357.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fathomless-headland-77357.git
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)


As an update, I deployed via Render which worked with no changes to the file structure / package / otherwise.
